# Sencha directions zoom

Tags: google-maps, zooming, sencha-touch

All,

When I use the Directions-service from Google Maps, it seems like the map always goes to zoom level 0 (I get an overview of the whole map).

When I set the code for the directions in comment, the zoom level is working well.

This is my code:

```
    /**
     * Update route
     */
    updateRoute: function ()
    {
        // route
        var start = "Belgium";
        var end = "France";
        var request =
        {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

       var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

       directionsDisplay.setMap(this.items.items[0].map);

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is what I get:
[image: Map]

Hopefully someone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map automatically zooms out to the range required to display the entire route.... I tried ur code.... If you select the start and origin as two places closer (preferably the same area/city) then the zoom level goes down to like 15-16 depending on the distance....

Since you've basically selected Belgium and France (both of which are really broad areas and not a single map point (so to speak) the zoom level goes down to 1 :)

Hope this helps